# ［I'm Done］ button is available after ［Save Edits］ even when nothing was edited in First Posts queue

Tags: bug, review, edits

In the First Posts review queue, it's possible to click <kbd>edit</kbd> to edit the post, then to immediately click <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> without having actually modified anything. If we do so, the button <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> becomes available even if we didn't actually do anything.

It's not really important, but it shouldn't be possible to click <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> unless we actually did something relevant.

Answer (score 5):

> It's not really important, but it shouldn't be possible to click <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> unless we actually did something relevant.

That is true, but let's see the impact of things. It doesn't actually matter. Whether you click *No action needed* or *I'm done*, it just goes to the next one.

What if you thought you needed to edit something and found out you didn't (hence you click *Save edit*)? Then you've reviewed the item. There is no harm in clicking *I'm done*.

So should it be fixed? I don't see why, it doesn't hurt anybody and it doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: Considering that it is observable (one can see whether a user clicked « No Action Needed » or « I'm Done »), it's misleading when you want to know whether someone just clicks « No Action Needed » without actually reading anything.

Comment: Do you really think robo reviewers are going though all the hassle to 'obfuscate' their robo reviewing? Trust me, they are lazy.

Comment: I don't know. Some people sometimes do thing to a great extent to be lazy.

Comment: I love the irony of that.